# Converter doc JSoup para string, aplicar Regex e retornar um valor em String

Tags: java, html, regex, android-studio, jsoup

Estou usando um exemplo que achei chamado *AndroidJsoup* para pegar o source `HTML` de uma certa página, mas não estou conseguindo obter apenas o trecho de código que desejo que está em um determinado `<script>`

Resumindo, o *AndroidJsoup* deveria rodar, pegando o `HTML`, aplicando um `regex` e retornando na `String resultado1`

Seguem meu **source** juntamente com a referência e exemplo da página `HTML` a ser pega. Também o `regex` retirado do meu script `php`.

Android **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.survivingwithandroid.jsoup;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.DataNode;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private EditText respText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText edtUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtURL);
    Button btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
    respText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtResp);
    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String siteUrl = edtUrl.getText().toString();
            ( new ParseURL() ).execute(new String[]{siteUrl});
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class ParseURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            Log.d("JSwa", "Connecting to ["+strings[0]+"]");
            Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
            Log.d("JSwa", "Connected to ["+strings[0]+"]");
            // Get document (HTML page) title
            String title = doc.title();
            Log.d("JSwA", "Title ["+title+"]");
            buffer.append("Title: " + title + "\r\n");

            // Get meta info
            Elements metaElems = doc.select("meta");
            buffer.append("META DATA\r\n");
            for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
                String name = metaElem.attr("name");
                String content = metaElem.attr("content");
                buffer.append("name ["+name+"] - content ["+content+"] \r\n");
            }

            Elements topicList = doc.select("h2.topic");
            buffer.append("Topic list\r\n");
            for (Element topic : topicList) {
                String data = topic.text();

                buffer.append("Data [" + data + "] \r\n");
            }

            //==========
            Elements scriptElements = doc.getElementsByTag("script");
            buffer.append("Variavel resultado1\r\n");
            for (Element element :scriptElements ){
                for (DataNode node : element.dataNodes()) {
                    System.out.println(node.getWholeData());
                    String scriptdata = node.getWholeData();
                    buffer.append("StriptData [" + scriptdata + "] \r\n");
                    //String resultado1
                }
                System.out.println("-------------------");
            }
            //==========

        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        respText.setText(s);
    }
}
}
```

Página exemplo **HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function var1() {
            ...etc...
        }
    </script>
    <title>Link das Pessoas</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>Conteudo</div>
    <script>
        function(...)
        etc valorM = (valores de xyz);
        etc valorE = (valores de xy);
        pegavalor(function() {
            ...funcoes_diversars(Conteudo dinamico e estatico...http://arquivosdofulano.com/pessoas 
                ...Conteudo dinamico e estatico)
        })
    </script>
    <div>Conteudo #2</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var google...
    </script>

</html>
```

**Regex** para pegar o valor de `resultado1`:

```
/(([http]+[https]:\/\/)(.*?).(com\/pessoas))/
```

> Nota: Retirei do php, são sei se precisa mudar algo nessa regex para o java.

Se possível um código que me permitisse adicionar outros `regex` para capturar outros valores em uma string. Ex `resultado2`...

Fonte [AndroidJsoup](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup.html)
Fonte [Source Code](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/tree/master/AndroidJSoup)

Comment: Não, é a url `http://arquivosdofulano.com/pessoas`, assim como outros valores que farei conforme preciso. Dê uma olhada na Regex. @re22

Comment: Até agora consegui refinar a busca e pegar somente o conteúdo do script  que desejo com `String procurarPor = "pegavalor(function()";
                        if(scriptdata.toLowerCase().contains(procurarPor.toLowerCase())){` Porem não consigo aplicar o regex de jeito nenhum, sempre retorna um `java.util.regex.Matcher@53724000`, vou continuar procurando quando o dia amanhecer até aparecer uma solução aqui, caso ache primeiro, posto, mas acho que não vai acontecer. =(

Comment: O problema foi resolvido, não da forma que eu esperava, lendo toda a página e passando o conteúdo para o `php` e nele aplicando as operações de busca com `regex` e retornando o valor, gostaria de ter respondido minha própria pergunta, mas como isso não se enquadra no que eu mesmo queria, que pode ser a duvida de outros, deixo aqui a alternativa, e a pergunta aberta para uma possível resposta, seja ela qual for, mas que sirva pelo menos como a minha alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que o conteúdo a ser extraído é `http://arquivosdofulano.com/pessoas` podemos criar a expressão regular da seguinte forma:

- Inicia com `http` ou `https` - `(http|https)` - O caractere `|` determina o operador `OU`;
- É seguido por `://` - `:\\/\\/ -`//` escapa caracteres que são usadas nas expressões regulares;
- Qualquer texto - `.*` - O `.` significa literalmente "qualquer caractere" e `*` é o quantificador de zero ou mais;
- `.com/pessoas` - `\\.com\\/pessoas` - `//` escapa caracteres que são usadas nas expressões regulares;

Juntando tudo isso a expressão regular será a seguinte:

```
(http|https):\\/\\/.*\\.com\\/pessoas
```

Para separar esse conteúdo utilizamos o agrupamento que é demonstrado por `()`.
Aplicando no seu código o resultado será o seguinte:

```
...
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((http|https):\\/\\/.*\\.com\\/pessoas)");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(scriptdata);

if (matcher.find()) {
  resultado1 = matcher.group(1);
}
...
```